# Debugging runtime stack error occurring once end of main function is reached

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I've converted some legacy Fortran code to C using the f2c converter (f2c), and I've created a Visual Studio 10 solution on Windows 7 (64-bit). I've also had to link my C++ program (test.cpp, containing my main function) with the f2c library (built on my system using nmake).

The program runs, but once the end of the main function is reached, I receive the following Debug error:

```
Stack around the variable 'qq' was corrupted
Stack around the variable 'pf' was corrupted
Stack around the variable 'ampls' was corrupted
```

I am wondering if this might be due to a "correction" made by the f2c converter in the converted C (from Fortran) file:

```
/* Parameter adjustments */
--x1;
--xabs;
--ximag;
--xreal;
--work4;
--work3;
--work2;
--work1;
--ampls;
--pf;
--qq;
--tri;
```

This seems a bit odd, since all of these variables are C arrays, and I think that the f2c program is simply doing some pointer arithmetic so that index 0 in the array becomes index 1, in a similar fashion to Fortran.

I don't know if this could also be due to something going wrong with the converted code accessing an element of the array that has not been allocated.

What is the best way to debug this error and fix it?

Comment: Well pointer arithmetic is what the `[]` operator does too... You would need to post your main function, but it's likely that you are writing beyond the bounds of the memory allocated for your arrays.

Comment: valgrind (linux only) is usually quite helpful in situations like this.

Comment: Maybe you can translate a simple Fortran program that produces similar output when the translated program is run. If it's simple enough, you should be able to post the Fortran and the translated source.  I'm guessing a program that just calls a function that adds one to each element in an array might do the trick.

Comment: Thanks to all who replied!  I will see if I can get Valgrind into analyzing the code.  I also suspect that something is going wrong with accessing the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potential reasons:

- This error is usually related to writing outside the bounds of an array (dynamic or static array). This error can occur by writing\getting a value in a -ve index or index >= size_of_array.
- This error also accurs if your pointer is not set to its correct location. (e.g. `ptr = 0`, `ptr = 55`, points to deleted (released; or has been free) memory, or any invalid address)

Best way to debug your error in my mind is to debug your prorgam step-by-step and watch those pointer values. There must be some wrong with them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Desolator.  I am now looking through the program and trying to find some sort of solution (step-by-step).

Answer (score 1):

What you say could be true. I would suggest to create a very small program that uses an array and decrements the pointer exactly as f2c does. Something like

```
int aa[10];
int *pa = aa;
--pa;
pa[1] = ...
```

That is, test the suspected code in the small scale. You might isolate the cause to the problem this way. (Finding a workaround is a different story)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've been trying similar code in both the main function and the function within the converted file, and it appears that something is going wrong with the indexing of the array. Your post helped me to narrow down the possibilities of what is actually happening here.

Answer (score 1):

Are you compiling with the debug versions of the crt?  That might give you some more information.

Also, is it possible that your library is built as C and your application is written as C++?

Those errors you mention are sometimes because of different calling conventions.  You do state it's a 64bit application, so it shouldn't be an issue (all 64bit apps use the same calling convention), but it's worth looking into.

Is it possible to add all the fortran converted code to visual studio and not do a seperate make?